# Why do I get an Uncaught TypeError: property 4 is undefined when looping through a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

So I am building Tetris. After creating an array, data, I am trying to implement gravity by checking 
 every string in an array if it's is "full" as well as being able the space below it being empty. However, it is giving me an error that suggests that something is undefined. The  I tried a for loop and a for...of loop, as well as Googling it.Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("edit");
var data = [];

function array(x, text) {
  var y = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
    y.push(text);
  }
  return y;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  data.push(array(10, "b"));
}

function draw() {
  var j;
  var i;
  var dataOut = data;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j] == "a" && data[i + 1][j] == "b") {
        if (i < data.length - 1) {
          dataOut[i][j] = "b";
          dataOut[i + 1][j] = "a";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  data = dataOut;
  console.log(data);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
data[0][4] = "a";
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Comment: `for (i of data)`    `i` here doesn't represent an index value into an array, a normal for loop would work better.  `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)`  also -> `data[i + 1]` if inside your loop your checking the next one, you might want `data.length - 1` too.

Comment: did you debug your app? with a simple console.log in order to see what contains you i and j variables... do you need the indexes of your arrays or rows of them? with for-of-loop you obtain values of array not indexes

Comment: Edited. Couldn't understand what the comments ment until now.

Answer (score 1):

with for-of-loop you iterate only objects/values of array and not indexes.

use only for-loop in order to use indexes

```
const editor = document.getElementById("edit");
var data = [];

function array(x, text) {
  var y = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
    y.push(text);
  }
  return y;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  data.push(array(10, "b"));
}

function draw() {
  var dataOut = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) { // logical error here
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j] == "a" && data[i + 1][j] == "b") {
        if (i < data.length - 1) {
          dataOut[i][j] = "b";
          dataOut[i + 1][j] = "a";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  data = dataOut;
  console.log(data);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
data[0][4] = "a";
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

**A simple example of for-of-loop**

```
const arr = ["aa","bb"]
for(let a of arr) console.log(a);
// will print
/*
aa
bb
*/
for(let a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) console.log(a);
// will print
/*
0
1
*/
```

Comment: Read the whole question. I said I used a for loop.

Comment: Plus, it is an array!

Comment: @JSScratchDouble  Do you read the comments?, have you tried using the `for loop`, but also remember the `data.length - 1` part too, or you will get a different error.  Doing those 2 things on your snippet stops the error..

Comment: @JSScratchDouble you have a logical error, listen me, copy my code and it will work like a charm. I already tried now on a console

Comment: @JSScratchDouble you exceed the size of array with i + 1, before it you (edited ) written for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++); correct it with for (i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++)